# Send authentication token again after reload the page with angular.js interceptor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to create login service using token-based authentication with AngularJS & NodeJS following [this approach](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543)

Using Angular interceptor I was able to send the authentication token that is saved in the local storage in each header request but when I reload the page the token isn't sent to the server and redirect me to the login page because the request doesn't have the token

how can I fix the reload page problem?

here's my angular code

```
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($q, $location,localStorageService) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers['auth'] = localStorageService.get('token');
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function(response) {
            if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                /* I need to resend the same request with token included here 
                 * if the token exist in local storage
                 */
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});

// then in app config 
app.config(function ($locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor'); 
});
```

Comment: This shouldn't be happening.  The interceptor is active for every request that goes to the server. What do you see when you put a breakpoint in the interceptor?  Also, it'd be helpful if you could post a simple plunkr/fiddle.

Comment: @FrailWords, yes the interceptor is active for every request that goes to the server in case you didn't reload the page but when you reload it will be new request coming out from the browser without any headers

Comment: Even on reload, the first thing that happens is that the angular app gets 'bootstrapped' i.e. your 'config' section would get executed.  Maybe your 'static' assets like 'js/css/images' etc.. for the login page are behind the security filter as well? Because they should be public to start with, when the user is not authenticated.

Comment: I tried what you just said using break-point on config section and NO, this is not happening, reload is new request without any headers, you are welcome to try it

Comment: also when I was searching for this problem I found some people talk about it but I couldn't find clear solution so it happens

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr/fiddle to try this out?

Comment: I will need to set server , so the plunker will be just front-end

Comment: What request redirects you to the login page?

Comment: @TareqSalaheldeen have u found any solution to this ?

Comment: @ANinJa No I didn't I had to change some of my architecture to avoid that